# registered instances of objects property are reset after ioc container resolve

Tags: c#, unit-testing, inversion-of-control, unity-container

When I resolve `Reminder` in the following code, the properties of `contact` and `profile` are not initialized. What am I missing?

```
public class Reminder : IReminder
{
    IProfile profile;
    IContact contact;
    public Reminder(IProfile profile, IContact contact)
    {
        this.profile = profile;
        this.contact = contact;
    }
}

IProfile profile;
IContact contact;
IReminder reminder;

[TestInitialize]
public void TestInit()
{
    var container = new UnityContainer();

    profile = new Profile() { ID = 1, Active = true };
    container.RegisterInstance(profile);

    contact = new Contact() { ID = 1, Active = true };
    container.RegisterInstance(contact);

    container.RegisterType<IContact, Contact>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());
    container.RegisterType<IProfile, Profile>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());

    reminder = container.Resolve<Reminder>();
}
```

When I examine `reminder`, I expect that contact `ID` and `Active` should be 1 and true respectively. But I see that it's 0 and false. Same with `profile`. Why?

Comment: Should those RegisterInstance calls look more like this: `container.RegisterInstance<IProfile>(profile);`?  In which case, you can skip doing `RegisterType` (or do RegisterType) and skip `RegisterInstance`.

Answer (score 0):

You've been mocked by the C# type inference. You wrote this:

```
container.RegisterInstance(profile);
```

But the C# compiler inferred the generic type like this:

```
container.RegisterInstance<Profile>(profile);
```

In other words, you told Unity: "Please Unity, in case someone requests for the exact type of 'Profile' (and not its base type or interface), please return this single instance".

The `Reminder` type however, does not depend on `Profile`; it depends on `IProfile` and you happen to have registered `IProfile` as follows:

```
container.RegisterType<IProfile, Profile>(
    new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());
```

This line is telling Unity: "In case someone requests for the exact type of `IProfile`, return an instance of `Profile` where this instances is cached for the lifetime of the container."

Since this is a completely different registration, Unity will create an instance for you.

The code you showed is probably just some toy code, but please note that IoC containers are meant to build up object graphs of services; classes in your application that contain the application's logic, but no behavior. Your `Contact`, `Person`, and `Reminder` classes are no services; they are entities. They are part of the state that you push through object graphs of services.

Injecting and resolving entities (and other data objects such as DTOs, messages or commands) will sone lead to lots of complexity and ambiguity in your container's registration. For instance, ask yourself, which Profile should the container return? The profile with ID 1, 2, 1000? It doesn't know. DI containers make their decisions based on type information, for the simple reason that they are not meant for creating runtime data. Instead, resolve [repositories](http://www.martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/repository.html), [command handlers](https://www.cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=91), and other services.